# Spring JPA mapping - first steps

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have class User:

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;
private String name;
private String password;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable
private List<Role> roles;
}
```

Class Owner inherits from User

```
@Entity
public class Owner extends User {

    private String pesel;
    private String adress;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private List<Pet> pets;
}
```

and Owner had Pet

```
public class Pet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String weight;

    @ManyToOne
    private Owner owner;
}
```

Why when starting the application gets the error:

> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property user found for type Pet!

--EDIT
First I have version, which was as follows:
[image]

now I try to share User instance to a doctor and the owner of the animal

[image]

The problem is that I do not know whether I am doing the mapping , and therefore wanted to ask whether it must look like

--edit2

I've simplified the scheme just a bit to better illustrate what happens

[image]

--edit3

Currently my Object's was presented:

```
@Entity
public class Pet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
    private String weight;
}
```

User

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String password;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="user_roles")
    private List<Role> roles;

}
```

PetOwner

```
@Entity
public class PetOwner extends User {

    private String pesel;
    private String adress;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="petOwner")
    private List<Pet> pets;
}
```

Comment: in class Pet, you have @manytoone private PetOwner petOwner. Where is class PetOwner? Also Class owner doesn't inherit from User, it extends user

Comment: Sry. Error in my post. Now it's ok

Comment: What are you actually trying to run? Where and when is this exception happening? You forgot to add that. And what are the parameters of @JoinTable for List<Role>?

Comment: I think the problem is with @OneToMany List<Pet>.  If the relationship is bidirectional, the non-owning OneToMany entity side must use the mappedBy element of the OneToMany annotation to specify the relationship field or property of the embeddable field or property on the owning side of the relationship. According to http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html

Comment: Look on that question now. I just edit the post

Comment: I think you need @OneToMany(......... , mappedBy="owner")
  private List<Pet> pets; and @ManyToOne(....)
  @JoinColumn(name="You don't have owner ID?")
  private Owner owner;

Comment: I change that and problem is the same: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property user found for type Pet!

Comment: lawl I don't know I tried :P

Comment: To state the obvious, Spring has nothing to do with this question as such. This is the JPA API, and should be addressed by looking at JPA reference documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replace

```
@ManyToOne
    private PetOwner petOwner;
```

for

```
 @ManyToOne
        private Owner petOwner;
```

and it works. Do you have a PetOwner class?

Also provide the log error to get more information about it

Comment: Yes I have. PetOwner class

Comment: OK, so your entity Owner is PetOwner, not Owner, also on your Pet entity you need to add @Entity

Comment: are you creating some Querys? I think, you are using a wrong parameter Name on one Query

Comment: Bingo  mvlaicevich. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Adamo I tried to help you too why you dont upvote my answer?